# Script is not running in Xcode build phase

Tags: xcode, react-native

In my package.json file I have a script that I'm running

```
node src/validateRun.js
```

I'm trying to run that script in the Xcode build phase. the script is located in the src/ so the build is successful but the script is never running.

Here is my build phase config:

```
shell: /bin/sh
```

```
SRC_DIR="../src/"
node "$SRC_DIR/validateRun.js"
```

is there any reason why the script is not running ?

Comment: Make sure that box 'Run script only when installing' isn't checked ? Have you tried adding an 'echo "Hello"' to your script, to make sure it's called and it's not a problem with node being undefined ?

Comment: The box is not checked, does it matter if it's a .js ? it should still run right ?

Comment: As long as this sub-shell knows 'node' command, it should be ok ! Have you looked at XCode run output ? if the shell doesn't find `node` , it might yell at you

Comment: It look like everything is good.. do you know how to make shell find node in case it's the problem

Comment: @Vinzzz is there any way to see my 'echo"Hello" in the metro bundler for example ? I added it to the Run Script build phase

Comment: Normally, you can see it in xcodebuild output. In the terminal, or from Xcode, in build phases I think (?)

Comment: @Vinzzz I got it working with my hello world echo but I got 'No package found in this path' is there any way to solve this ?

Comment: I don't know what the error you mention refers to - node package ? ...

Answer (score 0):

Apparently instead of execute `node file.js` you should type it like this:

```
/usr/local/bin/node your_file.js
```